# where is the NetBeans config file (netbeans.conf) located?

Tags: java, netbeans, config

my NetBeans has ugly fonts in interface. I'm going to make antialiasing for it. In internet I saw that there is should be

> -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on

in **netbeans_default_options**. This file should be located in /etc/netbeans.conf. But there isn't this file. I have NetBeans 6.8. Help, please.

**UPD**:

> [ockonal@wincode ~]$ cd ~/.netbeans/6.8/
>
> [ockonal@wincode 6.8]$ ls
>
> ant  build.properties  docs     lib   modules  sources
> update_tracking bin  config
> jsstubs  lock  native   update   var

**UPD2**
With utilite find I did:

> find / -name 'netbeans.conf'

This gave me:

> /usr/share/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf

Comment: In Win 7 w/ NB 8, this config file is located in `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\etc`.

Comment: Funny thing, I was searching for the file location to do the same thing and this thread saved me time

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In my NetBeans 6.7, this file is located at

```
{netbeans-installation-dir}/etc/netbeans.conf
```

I guess if you are using Windows, and the default folders, you should be able to find somewhere here:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\etc\netbeans.conf
```

On a linux box, you should be able to find the file somewhere here

> On Linux  the installer lets the user choose where you want to install NetBeans. You may find it under /home/yourname/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf or /opt/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf. [ from http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf ]

Comment: oh, sorry. I didn't write that I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: I haven't netbeans folder in /opt

Comment: I use NetBeans 7, and Netbeans configuration file path is `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\etc\netbeans.conf`

Answer (score 12):

On an ubuntu platform you can use the following command

```
locate netbeans.conf
```

to find where the netbeans files are located. It's the best way that provides with a precise location of your netbeans.conf file.

Hope this will help someone in need.

Comment: in MAC-OS also works  fine :)

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS X:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans XXX.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

(Where XXX is The installed version of NetBeans)

Example for NetBeans 8.0:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

Comment: For anyone using Finder to browse, right click the Netbeans application icon and click "Show Package Contents" to see the Contents folder.

Answer (score 4):

Current as of this date for Windows, go to `%APPDATA%\NetBeans`, then the version (I have 8.2 and dev). In there you'll find a config folder with tons of stuff under it. I came to this Q&A looking for info on fonts and colors. That info is now found under `config\Editors`. Some base info for your themes are in there under `FontsColors`. Styling and color details are under folder `text`, and then in subfolders similar to the above.

As an example, I went to tools>options>Fonts&Colors. I duplicated the Darcula profile into (my initials) TGDark to make changes. Then to Syntax, HTML, and "Javascript Embedded in HTML", I set the background color to #3F2B2B. Now, in the file system I found this setting under:

```
C:\Users\tony\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\dev\config\Editors\text\html\FontsColors\TGDark\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomFontsColors-tokenColorings.xml
```

And in that file, note the bgcolor:

```
<fontcolor bgColor="ff3f2b2b" default="default" name="javascript-embedded"/>
```

What an adventure...

Answer (score 1):

In Arch/Manjaro it's in `/usr/etc/netbeans.conf` (`locate netbeans.conf` is our friend)

Answer (score 0):

**in linux**:
usr/local/netbeans.{version}/etc/netbeans.conf

Answer (score 0):

In macOS for the latest release [Apache NetBeans 14](https://netbeans.apache.org) it's located here:

```
"/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 14.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf"
```