# Apache NetBeans 12.0 or 12.3 Window Tabs Label Text Language Issue

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

[image]

I am facing this weird language issue on Start Screen and as well as on other windows tab.
I have tried editing netbeans.conf files but no luck.

**Please help me to resolve this issue.**

**UPDATE:**

I have uninstalled version 12.0 and tried to install newer version 12.3 but issue is same as it was in 12.0

[image]

**Software Info**

**Product Version:** Apache NetBeans IDE 12.3

**Java:** 1.8.0_201; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.201-b09

**Runtime:** Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_201-b09

**System:** Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_us_UTF8 (nb)

**User directory:** C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.3

**Cache directory:** C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.3

Comment: Is it the same with Netbeans 12.3, the latest official release?

Comment: yes, it is same with Netbeans 12.3

Comment: Just to make sure, try also to clean all user config data. Quit Netbeans, delete the following directories and restart: <user_dir>/AppData/Local/Netbeans, <user_dir>/AppData/Roaming/Netbeans

Comment: @jjazzboss Thanks for the response. Deleted both directories but nothing changed. :(

Comment: @AmitSoni, please, update you questions. Add information from Help -> About. It includes such info as product version, updates, runtime, system.

Comment: @Dmitry.M ok, Thanks

Comment: have you try using different JDK/JRE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following options:

1. Use the latest JDK for Netbeans. The newest version for 1.8 is [281](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
   How to point NetBeans to the new JDK see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950960/5681468).
2. Try to set the default language option for non-Unicode programs in windows as mentioned [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.html).

> 1. Click **Start > Control Panel**.
> 2. Windows 10, Windows 8: Click Region
> 3. Windows 7: Click the **Administrative** tab.
>    (If there is no Advanced tab, then you are not logged in with
>    administrative privileges.)
> 4. Under the **Language for non-Unicode programs** section, select the desired language from the drop down menu.
> 5. Click **OK**.
> 6. Restart the computer to apply the change

3. If this doesn't help, try to change your java locale manually. You need to add something like this in the file [netbeans.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2447867/5681468) at the end of the variable netbeans_default_options:

   -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US -J-Duser.variant=UTF-8

Comment: JDK update and linked it to the NetBeans in netbeans.conf file did the trick. :) 
Thanks for the answer.. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change characters encoding for netbeans however my Netbeans version is differ from your but it should be the same approach fot thius. In my case i have netbeans config file (netbeans.conf) in a directory: **C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\etc**

I manually added -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the default option ("netbeans_default_options"). Below I paste my netbeans_default_options value:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true -J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. JDK update did the trick.